# Distribution of time per move

Tags: statistics

I am interested in the distribution of time (in seconds) that players take per move. To this end, I am looking for game traces that contain timing information.

I have found a number of chess databases on Google, but none of their traces contain this information.

Can somebody point me to a source of traces that contain the time when each move was taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FICS online game database](http://www.ficsgames.org) has move times, however those are mostly blitz and rapid time controls, so the time used will not be indicative of tournament play.

Note that you can filter the database to only allow for your desired time controls, as well as rating range.